# how to save a struct as a flattened json?

Tags: go

```golang
type Profile struct {
    Personal struct {
        Age int `json:"age"`
        Address string `json:"address"`
    } `json:"personal"`

    Education struct {
         Bachelor string `json:"bs"`
         Master string `json:"ms"`
    } `json:"education"`
}
```

`json.Marshal` produces json like

```
{
    "personal": { "age": 40, "address": "ABC" },
    "education" : { "bs": "AAA", "ms" :"BBB"}
}
```

How can I create a flattened json like

```
{
    "personal.age" : 40, "personal.address",
    "education.bs" : "AAA", "education.ms" : "BBB"
}
```

I've searched some posts, but couldn't find any other than flattening a map.

Comment: I've tried converting the struct to a map, flattening it, and then converting to json. This works but I've wondered if there is more efficient method. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way(using `encoding/json`):

```
type Personal struct {
        Age     int    `json:"personal.age"`
        Address string `json:"personal.address"`
}

type Education struct {
        Bachelor string `json:"education.bs"`
        Master   string `json:"education.ms"`
}

type Profile struct {
        Personal
        Education
}
```

but so you can see, it maybe not so elegant by changing struct tag to `person.age`.